# Is there a way to import HTML from my project files directly into my working HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, fetch-api

Once the HTMl import API was deprecated, we all lost a way to easily and directly bring HTML code from files into my working document in vanilla JS, and many answers to this question are either outdated or not helpful or way too hard (looking at you, AJAX). Since the introduction of ES modules, many assumed that there would be some collaboration on these parts, but it has remained relatively untouched. What do we do now, for front-end HTML imports?

Comment: Was there nothing in the [documentation after the announcement](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/07/web-components-time-to-upgrade) that helped?

Comment: @Andy it was a little rough around the edges--the issue wasn't that there was no solution, there just wasn't a nice clear one. The syntax for HTML imports is basic and sleek, so them removing it was a bit of a jolt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modern, clean solution to this problem is to make use of a few things:

1. ES6+ The javascript `fetch` API
2. ES8+ `async`/`await` functions
3. ES6+ Anonymous Javascript Functions

For Example,

Let's say that I want to import my navbar to each of my webpages. Typically, the solution post-html-imports is actually to embed an identical navbar in each page.

#### File Navbar.html

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#page1">Location 1</a>
  <a href="#page2">Location 2</a>
  <a href="#page3">Location 3</a>
  <!-- and so on... -->
</div>
```

This is a long, annoying, and repetitive bit of code to keep writing. However, we can embed it in every HTML page at the same spot using a combination of methods.

#### File Fetch.js

```
//Assuming that the code is in another file
async function fetchHTML(path = '/navbar.html'){
 let fetchResponse = await fetch(path); //fetch data from file at path
 let htmlString = await fetchResponse.text(); //get all text from file
 return htmlString; //return the HTML string. Is compatible with DOMParser.parseFromString()
}
```

As you can see above, the `async/await` combo is one of the most useful tricks for utilizing `fetch()`. Note that this file MUST be hosted in your project files, or else you will get a CORS error.

To actually implement this, use the following code.

#### importNavbar.js

```
(async function(path=''){
 let element = document.body; //this can be *any* DOM element, just select it first
 element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', await fetchHTML(path)); //This is a native method, has a nice tutorial on w3schools.
})()
```

Just add the following `HTML` to your main `HTML` file, and you should be all set!

#### index.html

```
<!-- at the end of your body element... -->
<script src="Fetch.js"></script>
<script src="importNavbar.js"></script>
<script src="YOUR ADDITIONAL FILES.js"></script>
```

Now, This Method is *awesome* if you need to load in a relatively large snippet. However, it isn't the fastest possible method. What works much quicker (and therefore is more supportive of other devices) is a small rewrite of our anonymous function as a proper one.

#### importNavbar.js, rewritten

```
function injectHTML(location='',HTMLstr=''){
 let element = document.body; //Identical to our original
 element.insertAdjacentHTML(location, HTMLstr);
}
injectHTML(`
template string containing your exact html
`);
```

Although this solution is not quite as robust, it *is* faster and for small strings, more reasonable.

I hope I answered some questions!

#### Compatibility Chart (no IE):

| code bit | chrome | edge | firefox | safari | opera |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `element.insertAdjacentHTML` | 1 | 4 | 8 | 4 | 7 |
| `fetch()` | 42 | 14 | 40 | 10.1 | 29 |
| `async/await` | 55 | 15 | 52 | 11 | 42 |
| template literals | ES6 | ES6 | ES6 | ES6 | ES6 |
| anonymous functions | ES6 | ES6 | ES6 | ES6 | ES6 |

If anybody has anything / optimizations to add, feel free to leave a comment.